Exposing what the compiler does for passing to a reference vs to a const reference
Compiling the code shown below, and examining the disassembly (objdump -DSs a.out > a.dis), I am unable to see any difference in what happens for invoking fun_ref(T &) and fun_const_ref(const T &). Is there no difference because the type of the parameter (T) is a std::vector<int>? Or is there never any difference in the steps of invocation, no matter what type the parameter type T is?
//  g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wfatal-errors -Werror example_objdump.cc
//  objdump -DSs a.out > a.dis

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) fun_ref(std::vector<int> & rv, const int a)
{
   std::cout << rv.at(a) << std::endl;
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) fun_const_ref(const std::vector<int> & crv, const int a)
{
   std::cout << crv.at(a) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v(128);
   volatile int a{3};

   v.at(a) = 1;
   fun_ref(v, a);
   v.at(a) = 2;
   fun_const_ref(v, a);
   return 0;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               


both functions use a reference.  A reference is just alias.  Any good compiler would make the code the same.  The only different is the const reference version stops you from accidently modifying the object, but that is a compile time check.

"is there never any difference in the steps of invocation..." That is implementation details. From standard's point of view, a const lvalue reference cannot be used to modify the referred to object while a non-const lvalue reference parameter can be.

The difference will be at compile time the compiler will disallow the const reference from doing mutation on the object.  If the non-const reference usage of the object is not doing any mutation on the object, it should not be a surprise that the generated code is identical or nearly identical (e.g., slightly different name mangling).

const-qualifiers, except when applied top-level to the declaration of an object variable, have no meaning in the compiled program (aside from different overload resolution choices). Its effect is purely compile-time. The only purpose of a const-qualifier is to make sure that expressions that would modify the referred-to object won't be allowed for code readability and maintainability.
Calling conventions consequently also do not differentiate based on it.
It is a bit different for const top-level on the declaration of an object variable. In that case it is also a promise to the compiler that the object will never be modified by the program and the compiler can optimize accordingly. This difference can sometimes be seen in different optimization choices by the compiler.

i dont understand why you make the distinction. Though, with non top level const the refered to object can be modified in case it is not acutually const. Do you mean that?
